# PHP select doesn't return values

Tags: php, mysql, ionic2

I have this code and I want to get the info in `medication table` and display it where `acc_id` in `account table` is `=` to `acc_id` in `medication table` and where `med_timeoftheday='morning'`

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
     $request = json_decode($postdata);
     $User_ID = $request->acccid;
     $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM account_info
     join medication on account_info.acc_id = medication.acc_id 
     where account_info.acc_id='%s'",
       mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$User_ID));
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows>0)
    {   
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {$data[]=$row;
        }

         echo json_encode($data);
    }

}
```

this is my ts :

how can I do that ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somehting like this:

```
SELECT * FROM medication 
  INNER JOIN account_info ON account_info.acc_id = medication.acc_id
WHERE medication.med_timeoftheday='morning'
```

Comment: you saved my life THANK YOU!

Comment: One more Question if you don't mind!The previous checks if `med_timeoftheday='morning'` he displays it on a page called `morning` how can I do so that if the user enters 2 values `ex: morning , noon` , it displays on `both pages morning and noon`

Comment: change the where to medication.med_timeoftheday='morning' OR medication.med_timeoftheday='noon'

Comment: but `OR`  wouldn't make it in a way that if he adds morning alone it will add it the the morning page too?

Comment: you'll need to validate that in php, and validate if the user selected 1 or more values

Answer (score 0):

firstly if you selected data from medication table so select first medication table and then using join with account table .

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM medication JOIN account_info ON account_info.acc_id = medication.acc_id WHERE medication.med_timeoftheday='morning'";
```